# Is there a definition of $[Y|X=x]$ as a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, definition, conditional-expectation

I recently witnessed statisticians discussing $[Y|X=x]$ as if it were a random variable. In particular, they were making assumptions about its distribution.

I am familiar with various definitions of conditional expectations, in particular with $\mathbb E[Y|X=x]$. And I know that $\mathbb E[Y|X]$ is a random variable. But don't remember ever seeing $[Y|X=x]$ as a random variable. What could be its definition?

**A bit of context added**: In the context of inference, let $X$ be the predictor r.v. and $Y$ the response. Define $r(x)= \mathbb E(Y|X = x)$ and call it the regression function. Then (according to the statisticians) we make an assumption on the distribution of $(Y|X = x)$.

Comment: See the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Formal_definition)

Comment: I suspect it's just a typo and they really mean $\mathbb E[Y\vert X=x]$.

Comment: Or they could be talking about the conditional distribution of $Y$ when given that $X=x$.

Comment: @Bowditch: But is $\mathbb E[Y|X=x]$ a random variable?

Comment: @Leo No, it is not. If they we assuming it's a random variable, then perhaps they meant $\mathbb E[Y\vert X]$? If you can give more context to your question, we may be able to give a more useful answer.

Comment: @Bowditch: I added a bit of context.

Comment: The conditional expectations is generally "slopilly" defined in - most - undergraduate text books. Maybe you would like to take a look at say Doob (1953) page 18: "Stochastic Processes" Wiley. Conditional expectation is a random variable :-)

Comment: In this case $ r(x)=E(Y|X=x) $ is not a random variable but an (unknown) set of constant (the regression function). However conditional on $X=x$, $Y$ is a random variable. When you write down a standard regression model you are specifying the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$

Comment: @Marja "See the definition" Hmmm, the definition of $[Y|X=x]$, you mean? I would be curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formally, $[Y|X=x]$ does not make sense. However, under some mild assumptions the probability measure $P(\,\cdot\,|X=x)$ exists for each $x$, so it makes sense to discuss the distribution of $Y$ with respect to this measure. This is what is really meant, and it is not surprising that a statistician would take this shortcut. After all, if you don't know any measure theory then what I have said might not mean anything to you, whereas talking about "conditional distributions" should have some intuition behind it - for example, if $Z$ is independent of $X$, the conditional distribution of $X^2-3XZ$ given $X=x$ should clearly be the same as the distribution of $x^2-3xZ$.